# Is there anyway to do something like ilike in sublime text2?

Tags: sublimetext2

So in Sublime Text 2, I can do control+shift+h to find something in all files, which is super helpful, but sometimes I kind of know what I need to find, but I don't know the exact name of it, so I thought it'd be helpful if I could do something like this:

```
Select * From table
WHERE colname ilike '%function%email%'
```

How do I do that?

Comment: In what editor is this possible? Or something like it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not perfectly clear from your question what you want.

You can search regular expression over multiple files by right-clicking a folder in the sidebar. More info http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/#Searching_multiple_files

You can do Go to anywhere autocompletion by typing the first letters of filename and function name (CMD+T on OSX). More info  http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/#Go_to_anywhere_shortcut

You can browse the functions in the current file with CMD+R OSX.

You can enhance autocompletion with SublimeCodeintel depending on your programming language:

https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel

Comment: Thanks Mikko. This helped a lot.